# Unity Gui fontSize dont change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using this code below to add a `Retry` and `Quit` button to the `GameOver` screen for my android game.

```
//if retry button is pressed load scene 0 the game
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/2-50,Screen.height/2 +100,200,140),"Retry?")){
        Application.LoadLevel(0);
    }
    //and quit button
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/2-50,Screen.height/2 +200,200,140),"Quit")){
        Application.Quit();
    }
```

But the fontSize of the Gui text is so small and no matter what I try then I cant make it bigger. What can I do to solve this.

Comment: Are you using a Gui Skin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use style object for this.

```
    GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle();
    style.fontSize = 20;
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/2-50,Screen.height/2 +100,200,140),"Retry?", style)){
        Application.LoadLevel(0);
    }
    //and quit button
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/2-50,Screen.height/2 +200,200,140),"Quit", style)){
        Application.Quit();
    }
```

But it is going to overwrite the original style so you probably want to make some other changes too. For example put these lines after declaration of ´style´ and before the first use of it:

```
    style.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;
    RectOffset margin = new RectOffset();
    margin.bottom = 10;
    margin.top = 10;
    style.margin = margin;
    style.normal.background = new Texture2D(1, 1);
```

For all possible settings check [unity's manuals.](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUIStyle.html)